# PySpark cannot match array

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark to do simple dataframe filtering.
The Spark dataframe `df_rules` looks like this:

[image]

I got this `df_rules` in this way:

```
from pyspark.ml.fpm import FPGrowth
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local")\
   .appName("Association Rules FP-Growth")\
   .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")\
   .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, [1, 2, 5]),
    (1, [1, 2, 3, 5]),
    (2, [1, 2])
], ["id", "items"])

fpGrowth = FPGrowth(itemsCol="items", minSupport=0.5, minConfidence=0.6)
model = fpGrowth.fit(df)

# Display frequent itemsets.
model.freqItemsets.show()

# Display generated association rules.
df_rules = model.associationRules
```

I just want to do `df_rules.where(df_rules.consequent == [1])`. It first gave me data type mismatch error, since `df_rules.consequent` is `array<bigint>`. So I converted `consequent` column data type through:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType
df_rules = df_rules.withColumn("consequent", df_rules.consequent.cast(ArrayType(IntegerType())))
```

But still got error:

[image]

Do you know how can I do filtering successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to convert `array<bigint>` to `array<int>`, just use long:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, lit

df_rules.where(df_rules.consequent == array(lit(1L)))
```